# How to hide Action Bar on my BDRL Web Part?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part

I want to hide only Action Bar not my navigation bar in may BDRL Web Part.
I know unchecked display toolbar hide but i want to hide only Action Bar not my paging bar.

[image]

Comment: are you mean BRDL is Business Data Related List web part ?!

Comment: Yes BDRL sorry for mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean BRDL is `Business Data Related List` (BDRL) , So you can hide the full toolbox as the following :

- Edit Web Part.
- Uncheck the Show toolbox.

If you need to only hide action button , try to

- Edit Page >  Add script editor in your page.

Use CSS as the following

```
<style>
.ms-core-menu-button 
{
display:none ! important;
}
</style>
```

**[output]**

[image]

Comment: Yes this is work for me. I apply CSS option. Thank You Qassas.

Comment: Hey Qassas one more thing i want to do how can i shift paging bar to left side?